Rehype or Remark: Trying to create a glossary parser plugin
I'm trying to replicate a glossary tool from WordPress (https://www.cminds.com/wordpress-plugins-library). The tool scans all blog posts and replaces names/aliases with markdown/html links to their respective glossary entries.
The people in the Astro Community suggest I try creating a Remark or Rehype plugin. (Rehype was expected to be easier).
My glossary contains entries with names (and aliases). In this example, I will pretend there are only two entries:

Acceptance Criteria - https://agilepainrelief.com/glossary/acceptance-criteria
User Stories - https://agilepainrelief.com/glossary/user-story

In reality, there are 150+ entries.
My plugin-to-be would scan the glossary entries to build a dictionary. Then it would iterate over all the blog entries, replacing any instances of each name/alias with a link to the same.
One of the more frequently asked questions in my Scrum workshops is around 
the difference between Definition of Done and Acceptance Criteria, 
and how they relate to User Stories.

One of the more frequently asked questions in my Scrum workshops is around 
the difference between Definition of Done and **[Acceptance Criteria](https://agilepainrelief.com/glossary/acceptance-criteria)**, 
and how they relate to [User Stories](https://agilepainrelief.com/glossary/user-story).

--
Like many I find it easier to work from example, especially since JavaScript/TypeScript aren't native languages for me.
What existing plugin would make a good jumping-off point? I assume cloning something like: https://github.com/lin-stephanie/rehype-callouts (which has a good test suite) is the way to go.
Do any existing plugins need to load data from files that should stored for the runtime of the plugin? It seems silly to rescan 150+ glossary files when they will be used  300+ times.
Key questions:

Which plugin(s) would make the best starting point to work from?
Which plugin(s), if any, load data once at the start of a long run?

If there is a clever of achieving this by gluing existing plugins together, that would e
